# Why i cant get the original name? Making test in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, phpunit, laravel-5

Im trying to test a controller using amazon s3, the problem is that i dont know how to set up the file to send it to the controller, im stuck in here, for this i use the example from the site of victor cruz but didnt work, in the controller can get the ClienteoriginalName, even dont pass the validation, need help on this  please!

this is the link to the example that i use (get in mind that this didnt help) victorcruz.me/testing-amazon-s3-file-upload-using-laravel-5-2-and-mockery/

The controller:

```
public function uploadPicture(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), User_picture::rules());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->respondFailedParametersValidation('Parameters failed validation for a user picture');
    }

    $picture = $request->file('picture');
    $imageFileName = $picture->getClientOriginalName();

    $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
    $matchThese = [
        'file' => $imageFileName,
        'user_id' => $user->id
    ];

    $sameImage = User_Picture::where($matchThese)->first();
    if ($sameImage) {
        $sameImage->active = True;
        $sameImage->save();

        return $this->responseOK();
    }

    try
    {
        $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
        $s3->put($imageFileName, file_get_contents($picture));
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        return $this->respondInternalError();
    }  

    $data = [
        'file' => $imageFileName,
        'url' => Storage::cloud()->url($imageFileName),
        'active' => True,
        'user_id' => $user->id
    ];

    $user_picture = User_Picture::create($data);
    if ($user_picture) {
        return $this->responseOk();
    }
}
```

The UnitTest:
    protected $storage;

```
protected $file;

protected $fileSystem;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    //Setup mocks
    $this->storage = $this->mock('Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory');
    $this->file = $this->mock('Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem');
    $this->fileSystem = $this->mock('Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem');

}

public function mock($class)
{
    $mock = Mockery::mock($class);      
    $this->app->instance($class, $mock);      
    return $mock;
}

/** @test */
public function testUpdateSuccess()
{
    $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();

    $user_picture = factory(App\User_Picture::class)->create(['user_id' => $user->id]);

    $file = new UploadedFile(
        base_path() . '/tests/data/image_test.png',
        'image_test.png',
        'image/png',
        6298,
        null,
        true
    );

    $files = [
        'api_token' => $user->api_token,
        'file' => $uploadedFile
    ];

    $this->getJson('api/v1/users/pic', 'POST', $files);
    $this->assertResponseStatus(200);
}
```

Hope you can help me with these!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code directly, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, the problem here was the `getJson` method, however if you need to upload a file in a phpunit test, don't forget that the `call` method get the following parameters:

`call($method, $uri, $parameters, $cookies, $files, $server, $content)`